# Endless loop keep creating new threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

I'm currently writing a basic webcrawler in C#. It multithreaded, but with the current structure it keep creating threads in an endless loop. What should I change in this code:

Crawler:

```
public static void Start(Uri url)
    {
        if (!RobotsParser.IsDomainParsed(LinkParser.GetDomainUrl(url)))
        {
            RobotsParser.Parse(url);
        }

        if (!CrawlQueue.CrawledList.Contains(url) && RobotsParser.IsCrawlingAllowed(url.ToString()))
        {
            CrawlQueue.CrawledList.Add(url);
            CrawlQueue.QueueList.Remove(url);

            //Crawling logic happens here...
            CrawlQueue.Add(LinkParser.Find(doc, responseUri));
            }
        }
    }
```

LinkParser:

```
public static HashSet<Uri> Find(HtmlDocument doc, string url)
{
   //returns list of found urls
    return list;
}
```

Queue (This is where the problem is)

```
internal static class CrawlQueue
{
    public static HashSet<Uri> QueueList = new HashSet<Uri>();
    public static HashSet<Uri> CrawledList = new HashSet<Uri>();

    private static void Start()
    {
        Parallel.ForEach(QueueList.ToList(), new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 7 }, url =>
        {
            try { CrawlEngine.Start(url); }
            catch (Exception e) { Debug.WriteLine(url + " "+ e.ToString()); }
        });
    }

    public static void Add(HashSet<Uri> list)
    {
        int counter = 0;
        foreach (var site in list.Where(site => !QueueList.Contains(site)))
        {
            QueueList.Add(site);
            counter++;
        }

        if (counter >= 1)
        {
            Logging.Log(counter + " items added to crawling queue");
            Start();
        }
    }
}
```

For what sort of design should I go when working through the list?

Comment: You likely don't need more than a single thread, as the vast majority of the work is IO bound.

Comment: Why use multithreading in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem of many threads being spawned is the recursive call to `Start()` combined with `Parallel.ForEach` (a blocking call). You should use something like `Task.Factory.StartNew()` instead, to allow a call to `Start()` to exit while child tasks are running. You will probably need to refactor your code to return the resulting tasks as well so that you can know when everything is done.

As comments mention, you probably don't need a blocking multithreaded solution (you should be using non-blocking IO), but that's a much bigger change.